# wxPython sweep panels by touch rather than button

Tags: python, wxpython

Is there a way to change panels with sweep to right or left?
The change of the panels using a button is available and I have implemented it. Now, I would like to use a sweep event to call the switch panel function not the press of a button.

Comment: Where does this `sweep` event come from? If you are monitoring a device sending sweep events, you simply have to generate a custom event using `wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()` and `bind` a callback function to it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, the sweep comes from a touchscreen. Basically, a touch from say right to left or left to right would be the event. Is there such library already in wxpython?

Comment: If you are not actively monitoring an input device, I guess you may get some mileage out of `wx.Window.EnableTouchEvents(self, eventsMask)`. This purports to offer: `wx.LongPressEvent, wx.PanGestureEvent, wx.PressAndTapEvent, wx.RotateGestureEvent, wx.TwoFingerTapEvent, wx.ZoomGestureEvent`, although I've never used them myself.

Comment: Thanks these are useful, I read their documentation and trying to see if I can get them do what I want.

Comment: If you get them to work, do please answer your own question, with a simple working example, for our benefit.